The type org.bouncycastle.cms.cmsutils is not visible
I want to subclass some BC classes, in my Java project, but I faced issue with import of CMSUtils class. In order to reproduce issue in a simple project, I created quick-start Maven project (Eclipse 2024-06 IDE). Here are some details:
in pom.xml:
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
   <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk18on</artifactId>
   <version>1.78.1</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
   <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
   <version>1.78.1</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
   <artifactId>bcutil-jdk18on</artifactId>
   <version>1.78.1</version>
 </dependency>


In .java file:
package cmstest;

import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedStream;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils;

public class App {
    public static void main( String\[\] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}


So, on CMSUtils import, IDE reports: "The type org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils is not visible". On the other hand, it does not complain on other import, which is here only to show that other class from same .jar is visible.
I looked at content of bcpkix-jdk18on-1.78.1.jar file, and can see both classes. Therefore, it is strange that import of CMSUtils is not possible.
Any idea what's wrong here?
EDITED, 05.09.2024.
Working on some project that is using BC classes, I found that I need customized way of digital signing, that does not include private key from some file, but private key on smartcard. In order to customize BC classes, I tried with subclassing some of BC classes, but under my package (for example com.name.package). Soon, I discovered issue with visibility of CMSUtils class, as I described before.

Can't be done because SMSUtils only contains statics. See my answer. Possibly update the question with what problem you are trying to solve and we may be able to help.

Hi John, I updated my initial question (sorry for late response, due to hot summer). Furthermore, thanks to your answer, I found one possible way to solve this issue. I'll give my answer in a few days.

The class org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils is not declared public so you can't extend/override.
There is a hack. Create a package with the same path as CMSUtils, ie org.bouncycastle.cms and you will be allowed to override.
However, CMSUtils only contains static methods, which can't be overridden.

Working on some project that is using BC classes, I found that I need customized way of digital signing, that does not include private key from some file, but private key on smartcard. In order to customize BC classes, I tried with subclassing some of BC classes, but under my package (for example com.name.package). Soon, I discovered issue with visibility of CMSUtils class, as I described before.
I'll try to give answer on my question, describing what I've done.
According to suggestions by John, I created separated packages under my app package, that includes copies of original BC classes (like org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms, org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs, ...). This approach was good for debugging what's going on in BC classes, but is not good as final solution, due to fact that you cannot use your "local" copies of BC classes, along with "public" classes, as these two subsets of libraries are not signed with same key, and compiler report warnings/errors. In order to use your local copies, you must remove signature from "public" BC classes that you are using within your project. But, when you develop some project that includes BC classes (public or your local copies), it is not good solution to public application that contain "BC" classes with removed signature. Someone (everyone) would suspect that application you relased could be used in wrong manner...
Anyway, after using copies of BC classes along with public BC classes (with removed signature), I debugged some of BC classes and found a way what to do in order to get what I want. At the end, I removed copies of BC classes, returned back public BC classes with signatures, and created my own subclasses (few of them), that worked well. Now, I have my own way to create digital signature, using private key on smartcard. My new BC-subclasses are located in com.name.package.bc (example), as there is no need to be under certain org.bouncycastle.xxx sub-package.
I hope this will help someone, if needed, but could be also better way to customize BC classes.
